# JFreechart set height of vertical data

Tags: jfreechart

Has anyone an idea how i could set the height of the data vertical wise?

[image]
<sub>(source: [gabathuler.de](http://d3.gabathuler.de/jfreechart.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html), shown [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html), is a good example.